# Configuring Route 53 DNS migrated from Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Quick Help Please....

I recently migrated my DSN from Godaddy to AWS Route 53.  When doing the process I had checked "automatically import....".  So I thought everything would propagate automatically.

Now after 7+ days when Godaddy finally released me, nothing is working.  I am not an expert on DNS.  And Site is down.  Priority now is getting "www.example.com" to point to my ip address.

I have attached screen shot.  What else needs to be done?

I should also add this was launched into a VPC.

**Update** I have attached an image of my Named Servers.

[image]

[image: AWS Route 53]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using an IP address for S3. You need to change the record type to CNAME, and point it to the domain name S3 tells you to use. Honestly that's how it should have been set up on GoDaddy as well.

Here are the instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

You don't need to be an "expert on DNS" to set this stuff up. You just need to follow the instructions.

Also, when you say "this was launched into a VPC" what do you mean by that? Route53 offers public and private DNS zones. Public zones are similar to your previous GoDaddy DNS and are what you need to use for a public website. Private DNS zones are for DNS records you only want to resolve from within your VPC.

Comment: Sorry - in my haste to write this I accidentally put "S3" when I meant to say "Route 53".  Regarding the VPC.  If I go to my EC2 console, the instance has a "VPC ID" value.  Honestly I know next to anything about this.  Please help if you can - website is down!!!

Comment: So this is an EC2 instance inside a VPC? Does it have a public IP address? Perhaps an Elastic IP address? Is the address in Route53 not the same as the address that is showing in the EC2 console?

Comment: Did you transfer the domain registration to Route53 or just the DNS servers? If just DNS, did you properly configure GoDaddy to use the new DNS servers provided by Amazon?

Comment: By the way I just did a whois on your domain: http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=embeddedanalytics.com&type=domain and it appears to still be using domaincontrol.com (GoDaddy) DNS servers, not Route53 servers.

Comment: I am able to remote desktop.  So the "public ip" is working.  At this point I am not even concerned with elastic ip.  I **thought** I transferred everything.  Now when I go to Godaddy and go to "domains" there are none.  On route 53 they show.  Is there a way to private message you?  I am desperate - and would pay $$ to get this resolved.  I could get you into aws console.

Comment: Go to Route53 console -> Registered Domains. Do you see your domain listed in there? If not, check the "Pending Requests" section.

Comment: Yes - they are in Registered Domains section.  Up until this morning, for the last week since I made the request to transfer out of GoDaddy, they were showing as "pending".  Then this morning I got verifications emai from AWS and a "Sorry to see you Go" email from GoDaddy.

Comment: You need to copy the 4 DNS name server addresses in the Route53 "Hosted Zones" section. Then go to the Route53 "Registered Domains" section and update/change the name servers to be those 4 that you just copied. You should have done this days ago. At this point your site might be down for up to 48 hours while these changes propagate.

Comment: I added a picture....  so I have to update the Named Servers where it is currently set to "ns53.domaincontrol.com"?

Comment: Yes, domaincontrol.com are GoDaddy servers. So all requests for your domain are still going to GoDaddy, which doesn't have your domain anymore. You need to update those to the new servers provided by Amazon.

Comment: Ok - thanks.  Did that.  Got message "Your request for update nameserver was successfully submitted. You will receive an email when it is done."

Comment: As I said before, the EC2 instance has a VPC ID.  When I create the Hosted Zone, should I select "Public Hosted Zone" or "Private Hosted Zone for Amazon VPC"?  Also, eventually I will utilize an Elastic IP.  But I just want to get things back up with "Public IP".  Ok to use my Public IP (I understand I will need to update with elastic ip later)

Comment: Public Hosted Zone is what you want

Comment: Ok.  Still not seeing site.  Gut wrenching to say the least.  I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at screen shots https://s3.amazonaws.com/eaconfigureroute53/RegisteredDomains.png and https://s3.amazonaws.com/eaconfigureroute53/eaRecordSets.png  Is everything correct?  So it is just a waiting game now?  I know it can be "up to 48 hours"...  But in the past when I have done ip address modifications it seems to propagate much more quickly.  Is propagation of Name Servers longer?

Comment: Your settings look correct, and the correct name servers how show up on internic.net. Like I said, it can take up to 48 hours for a name server change to propagate across the internet, so if you didn't want your site to be down you should have done this a few days ago.

Comment: live and learn....  Don't know much about DNS.  When going through the steps on AWS there was a "import DNS Zone Files Automatically" option.  Or something to that extent.  I was under the impression everything would have been done for me.  I was wrong.  Or could this also be GoDaddy not being nice when people leave them?  Would have thought if I was "Transferring" then AWS would have updated name servers to theirs.

Comment: This had nothing to do with the DNS zone file, and is not GoDaddy's fault. You didn't set the correct name servers when setting up domain registration on Amazon, you just copied the settings from GoDaddy, which would be incorrect once you transferred over from GoDaddy. In the future I would suggest one of the following: 1. read up on the subject before making changes, 2. do a test run with another domain, or 3. contract the work to someone who understand what they are doing

Comment: There was no need to even switch registration to Amazon in order to use Route53 DNS servers. and switching your registration without correctly managing the settings is why your site isn't accessible.

Comment: I went to Route53 because I wanted to start using CloudFront with my domain name.  In order to do this, doesn't the domain name need to be under the control of Route53?

Comment: Just the DNS servers, not the domain name registration.